# Assigning weights to Columns and Rows in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to give equal spacing to all rows in Flutter App.
is there anything like weights or any such widget which can be used.
For example, I have 2 Row elements in my app. I want both elements to take equal/half width of the screen.

Comment: I think AspectRatio class is useful https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html

Answer (score 8):

Inside a `Flex` (i.e. `Row` or `Column`), `Expanded` consumes the remaining available space. If you put two Expandeds in the same Flex they share the remaining available space equally (by default).

You assign 'weights' to Expandeds with their `flex` parameter, which would allow you to, say, have them share the remaining space 60/40, instead of 50/50, etc.

Answer (score 4):

**Flexible** is your friend

Example with the **Row**:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Flexible(
        flex: 5,
        child: SomeFirstWidget(),
      ),
      Flexible(
        flex: 2,
        child: SomeSecondWidget(),
    ],
)
```

The flex param is the weight.

Answer (score 1):

While you can use the AspectRatio class to evenly manage your widgets it would make more sense to your needs to just align the widgets evenly in a row. Both rows and columns have a mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment class.

Just wrap the widgets you want to space evenly in a Column and set it:

```
Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly ... )
```

You can also use spaceBetween and spaceAround like given [here](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/MainAxisAlignment-class.html).